# Handling Error Pages in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have one URL in **start_urls**

The first time the crawler loads the page, it is first shown a 403 error page after which the crawler shuts down.

What I need to do is fill out a captcha on that page and it will then let me access the page. I know how to write the code for bypassing the captcha but where do I put this code in my spider class?

I need to add this on other pages as well when it encounters the same problem.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://mydomain.com/categories"]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403] #Where do I now add the captcha bypass code?
    download_delay = 5
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item (self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 7):

Set `handle_httpstatus_list` to treat `403` a successful response code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403]
```

As for bypassing the actual captcha, you need to override `parse` to handle all pages with a `403` response code differently:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if response.status_code == 403:
        return self.handle_captcha(response):

    yield CrawlSpider.parse(self, response)

def handle_captcha(self, response):
    # Fill in the captcha and send a new request
    return Request(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. Scrapy is still exiting as it encounters the 403 error.

Comment: @Crypto: The crawler will shut down for a variety of reasons. What's the full traceback?

Comment: There is no traceback. When it encouters the 403 error on the starting page, it just quits saying "INFO: Closing spider (finished)"

Comment: I had renamed the spider file recently. After I deleted the corresponding .pyc file, the changes are reflected. So now that it's treating 403 as a valid page, where do I add my handler to do write the captcha code?

Comment: @Crypto: Wherever you would if the 403 response code was never sent. Like I said, it depends on your source code.

Comment: There is a problem with yield super(CrawlSpider, self).parse(response)

The traceback says:


   File "/home/crypto/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 56, in parse
     raise NotImplementedError
 exceptions.NotImplementedError:

Comment: @Crypto: A bit late, but that last line should be `yield CrawlSpider.parse(self, response)`.